# Funding sources in the US for applied OR projects

Tags: research

What types of organizations/sponsors in the US support applied OR research? I'm familiar with NSF and NIH.

Answer (score 9):

If your application can be applied to naval issues, the Office of Naval Research has been a great supporter of OR. https://www.onr.navy.mil/en/Science-Technology/Departments/Code-31/All-Programs/311-Mathematics-Computers-Research/computational-methods-resource-optimization is the more applied program.

Answer (score 2):

I have also heard the following offices/agencies in the Department of Defense support this type of work:

- Army Research Office
- Air Force Office of Scientific Research (AFOSR)
- Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency (DARPA)